# C++ DLL only reading first char of a string contained in a safearray

Tags: c++, string, dll, vb6, safearray

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a user defined structure from a VB6 application to a C++ DLL.

Here's a sample of my VB6 code :

```
Private Type ObjetVB  
    Rank As Integer
    Id As String
End Type  

Private Declare Sub testLObj Lib "D:\TestDLL.dll" (Tab_Obj() As ObjetVB)
Private Declare Sub testObj Lib "D:\TestDLL.dll" (ByRef Obj As ObjetVB)

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim elements(1 To 4) As ObjetVB, i As Long

    For i = 1 To 4
        elements(i).Rank = i
        elements(i).Id = "Pouet"
    Next

    testLObj elements()
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Dim ObjCrash As ObjetVB

    ObjCrash.Rank = 1
    ObjCrash.Id = "Pouet"

    testObj ObjCrash

End Sub
```

And a sample of my C++ code :

```
struct ObjetVB
{
    short Rank;
    char* Id;
};

void videFichier()
{
    ofstream fichier("../../../log.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);
    if(fichier)
    {    
        fichier.close();
    }
}    

int Log(ObjetVB ObjInput)  
{
    ofstream fichier("../../../log.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    if(fichier)
    {
        fichier << ObjInput.Rank << endl << "Id : " << ObjInput.Id << endl << endl;
        fichier.close();
    }
    return 0;
}

void __stdcall testObj (ObjetVB* ObjInput)  
{
    videFichier();
    log(*ObjInput);
}

void __stdcall testLObj (SAFEARRAY **Tab_Obj)
{
    ObjetVB *elt;
    HRESULT ret;
    unsigned long i;
    videFichier();

    if ((ret = SafeArrayAccessData(*Tab_Obj,(void **) &elt))==S_OK)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < (*Tab_Obj)->rgsabound->cElements; i++)
        {
            Log(elt[i]);
        } 
        SafeArrayUnaccessData(*Tab_Obj);
    }
}
```

My Issue is, when I click "Command2", my log file looks like this :

```
1  
Id : Pouet
```

Whereas, when I click "Command1", it looks like this :

```
1
Id : P

2
Id : P

3
Id : P

4
Id : P
```

Why does my C++ DLL recognize "char* Id" as a chain of characters when I pass a single item whereas when I use an array of items it looks like it recognizes it as a pointer to the first character?

And, most notably, how could I fix it? I tried using LBSTR instead of char* in my c++ struct, it didn't fix it, I also tried to add "elements(i).Id = String (255, vbNullChar)" berfore initializing the VB6 strings, but it didn't prove to be helpful either.

As usual, I'd like to thank all of you for the time you put into reading and trying to help.

On a side note : English is a foreign langage to me, so I hope I'm almost understandable and, of course, I apologize if it's not the case.

**Edit :**

I don't know if it could help, but after trying what Mark Bertenshaw suggested, I also tried this :
in VB6 :

```
Id As String * 10
```

in C++ :

```
char Id[10];
```

Which gave this weird result :

```
Objet : 
32
Id : P

Objet : 
1
Id :  

Objet : 
32
Id : P

Objet : 
2
Id :
```

Comment: Putting user defined types into a safearray leads to tedious coding. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , basically you have to fetch a `IRecordInfo` pointer and use the convenience methods to access your data.

Answer (score 2):

VB6 returns you a BSTR not a char array.  A BSTR will be full of wide characters, for one.  For the standard roman alphabet the 2 byte encoding, I believe, is the same as ASCII but the second byte is 0 and hence your string appears to have zero length.

you could use a wchar_t* instead of the char* and you'll find everything seems to work.  This isn't the best way to do it though as you can't guarantee that wchar_t and BSTR are the same size.

Your best bet is to use the [ConvertBSTRToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewezf1f6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function.

Comment: It doesn't look like an encoding issue as it works perfectly with the testObj functon that uses only a ByRef item instead of a Safearray of items. I also tried the wchar_t* and it definitely looks like this way of doing it generates encoding issues.

Comment: Have you got Command1_Click() and Command2_Click() the wrong way round?

Comment: When VB6 passes strings to native APIs (including within UDTs) it automatically converts the data to ANSI, so `testObj` should see the data fine.  I don't know why it would work differently for an array of UDTs though...

Answer (score 2):

What is happening here is that VB is being "helpful", and automatically converting the 2 byte Unicode character string (BSTR) in ID to a 1-byte ANSI character string (char*) for you. However, I am not entirely sure what it is doing with the strings when you put your VB Type into an array.

One possibility is that the packing of the ObjetVB structure is causing you problems. Try defining it like this:

```
Private Type ObjetVB
   Id As String        ' 4 bytes
   Rank As Integer     ' 2 bytes
End Type   

struct ObjetVB
{
    char* Id;          // 4 bytes
    short Rank;        // 2 bytes
}
```